# How to use $.ajax with then()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use AJAX to send some data to my apache/php webserver (XAMPP). 
I already got it running with the shorthand syntax $.post, the code looks like this:

```
return $.post('http://localhost:8099/login.php', {
      loginDataInput : loginDataInput
    }).then((response) => {
      //response = JSON.parse(response)
      return response
    })
```

But now I'm trying to use the long form, $.ajax, like this:

```
return $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8099/login.php',
      data: loginDataInput
  }).then((response) => {
    return response
  })
```

And it doesnt seem to work. 
I debugged the $_POST array on php side, the datainput itself is changed, the dots become underscores when I use $.ajax syntax (see below). How do I prevent that?

$_POST array echoed via json_encode after AJAX call with $.post syntax:

```
{"loginDataInput":"{\"loginDataMailInput\":\"gruss@imbus.de\",\"loginDataPasswordInput\":\"test2\"}"}
```

$_POST array echoed via json_encode after AJAX call with $.ajax syntax:

```
{"{\"loginDataMailInput\":\"gruss@imbus_de\",\"loginDataPasswordInput\":\"test2\"}":""}
```

For my $.ajax version I used the jquery Doc 
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
Which showed me the $.ajax equivalent to the $.post shorthand. 
I left out datatype because I want to use intelligent guess. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @t.niese Okay, but if its server side, why is it affected by the way I make my AJAX call on the frontend? For real, if I use $.post shorthand, everything looks fine on the server side as well!

Comment: try to change `data: loginDataInput` to `data: { loginDataInput: loginDataInput }` and tell us what it changes

Comment: You can add `dataType: "json"` to the ajax request.

Comment: @designtocode this is not about the datatype attribute. datatype specifies the expected return value. 
I specified contentType as "json" but for some reason I get a CORS error then, telling me that the same origin policy doesnt allow reading the remote source. 

CORS works if I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain as contentType or leave it at default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loginDataInput` needs be inside an object.

```
return $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8099/login.php',
      data: {
        loginDataInput: loginDataInput
      }
  }).then((response) => {
    return response
  })
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `data` can accept objects or strings as per documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. So it doesn't 'need' to be inside a object.

Comment: @designtocode I think you skipped the word **inside**. It's maybe not very well phrased but he's right, if the OP wants the data in the same format in `ajax` than in the previous version with `post`, that's what needs to be done